# Exit original function from another procedure

Tags: c#, function, procedure

Is there any way in C# to exit a function from within another procedure?

Example:

```
void myFunction()
{
    checkLogin();    //make sure a user is logged in
    doOtherStuff();  //continue with other stuff
}
void checkLogin()
{
    if(loggedIn==false)
    {
        exitOriginalFunction(); // exit myFunction
    }
}
```

Comment: return a value indicating whether or not to continue.  or refactor so such a thing is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void myFunction()
{
    if(!checkLogin())
       return;    //make sure a user is logged in
    doOtherStuff();  //continue with other stuff
}
void checkLogin()
{
    if(loggedIn==false)
    {
        return false; // exit myFunction
    }
    return true;
}
```